# Show Tree View in notepad++ when used in WinPE

Tags: notepad++, winpe

How to use `notepad++` in `WinPE` and show the tree view.

When using `notepad++` in `WinPE` (64bit version) it doesn't show the tree view. Neither it shows the `open` dialog.

Also other programms like e.g. explorer++ don't show the tree view.

This is not a duplicate of [Show files in Navigation Pane (Tree View) in Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/q/1234491/543913)

I've tried the instructions in [Show files in Navigation Pane (Tree View) in Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/q/1234491/543913) but it doesn't work in WinPE

Comment: Not a specific answer.. but try [Hiren's](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) fancy schmancy free and legal version of the windows PE environment.  It has everything you can think of and the treeview does indeed work.  We use it at work for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

In notepad++ community forum there is a thread explaining why it probably won't work in WinPE: see [WinPE File Explorer not working](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20907/winpe-file-explorer-not-working)